# How to add 5 minutes to current datetime on php < 5.3

Tags: php, datetime

I want to add 5 minutes to this date: `2011-04-8 08:29:49`

```
$date = '2011-04-8 08:29:49';
```

When I use `strtotime` I am always getting `1970-01-01 08:33:31`

How do I add correctly 5 minutes to `2011-04-8 08:29:49`?

Comment: What is the exact code that you tried?

Comment: `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+5 minutes', $currenttime))`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
$date = '2011-04-8 08:29:49';
$currentDate = strtotime($date);
$futureDate = $currentDate+(60*5);
$formatDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $futureDate);
```

Now, the result is **2011-04-08 08:34:49** and is stored inside `$formatDate`

Enjoy! :)

Answer (score 39):

Try this:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+5 minutes', strtotime('2011-04-8 08:29:49')));
```

Answer (score 14):

```
$expire_stamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+5 min"));
$now_stamp    = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

echo "Right now: " . $now_stamp;
echo "5 minutes from right now: " . $expire_stamp;
```

Results in:

2012-09-30 09:00:03

2012-09-30 09:05:03

Answer (score 6):

```
$date = '2011-04-8 08:29:49';
$newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($date." +5 minutes"))
```

Answer (score 5):

For adding

```
$date = new DateTime('2014-02-20 14:20:00');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P0DT0H5M0S'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
It add 5minutes

For subtracting

$date = new DateTime('2014-02-20 14:20:00');
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P0DT0H5M0S'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

It subtract 5 minutes
```

Comment: The OP question is related to PHP < 5.3; your answer is only valid for PHP >= 5.3.

Answer (score 4):

If i'm right in thinking.

If you convert your date to a unix timestamp via strtotime(), then just add 300 (5min * 60 seconds) to that number.

```
$timestamp = strtotime($date) + (5*60)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

more illustrative for simple and clear solution

```
    $date = '2011-04-8 08:29:49';
    $newtimestamp = strtotime($date. ' + 5 minute');//gets timestamp
    //convert into whichever format you need 
    $newdate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newtimestamp);//it prints 2011-04-08 08:34:49
```