# Adding minutes to date formatting syntax

Tags: php, date, time

I am having trouble adding a time and time interval to a date.

I use a javascript datepicker that gives date in the form: 05/06/2013

I can convert this into a date time format with

```
$eventdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($eventdate));
```

This gives: `2013-05-06 00:00:00`

I get the time from a separate variable in minutes.  Eight o'clock would be 480.

However, I cannot seem to find syntax to add 480 minutes to the date.

Have tried, for example,

```
echo date("Y/m/d h:i:s", strtotime("+480 minutes", $eventdate));
```

but this gives me the default 1969 date.

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5608967/how-to-add-5-minutes-to-current-datetime-on-php-5-3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, it's easier to work with:

```
$eventdate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d h:i:s', $eventdate);
$eventdate->modify('+480 minutes');

echo $eventdate->format('Y/m/d h:i:s');
```

Comment: To save back in the dbase in the datetime format can I just use $eventdate = $eventdate->format('Y/m/d h:i:s');

Comment: Got call to undefined method DateTime::createFromFormat() error.  Am running php 5.2

Comment: Try using the constructor then - `$eventdate = new DateTime($eventdate);`

Comment: Got call to undefined method DateTime::createFromFormat() error.  Am running php 5.2

Comment: Thought this would be trivial but an having trouble substituting variable for 480 modify('+$num minutes') and variants does not work

Comment: `$eventdate->modify('+' . $num . ' minutes');` read about [concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)